# Почему не работает функция для стека?

Tags: c++

```
class Stack {
  private:
    int maxSize, top;
    char *array_stack;

  public:
     Stack(int n) {
        array_stack = new char[n];
         maxSize = n;
         top = 0;
    }
    char Show(char a) // Вот эта функция почему-то не работает
    {
        return array_stack[--a];
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
            cout << array_stack[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack OPZ(20);
    string str;

    cin >> str;
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (str[j] == OPZ.Show(str[j])) {
            cout << "Работает!";
        }
    }
    OPZ.print();
}
```

`char Show(char a)` - вот эта функция почему-то не работает. Что не то? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Кто удаляет мой вопрос?!

Comment: А что должна делать эта ф-ция? Понимаете ли, действие --a для локальной переменной ф-ции в данном случае бессмысленно. Что под этим подразумевалось?

Comment: Почему? Ну я хочу увидеть последний элемент стека @gecube

Ну там еще перед if(str[j] == OPZ.Show, стоит OPZ.push(char a);

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, потому что можно было написать `a - 1` вместо `--a`, т.к. измененное значение все равно теряется.
Во-вторых, вероятно нужно при вызове OPZ.Show() передавать не код символа, т.е. не str[j], а номер элемента в стэке, т.е. `j`